# Word/phrase to refer to things you bring to a place to stay the night?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Example:

> We are going to a trip tomorrow and staying the night in a hotel.
>   Don't forget to bring your [...].

I thought about **stuff** but I'm looking for something less ambiguous (it can be informal).

Comment: personal items?

Comment: It may depend on the proclivities of the person being addressed. Could range from *teddy bear* to *whips and chains*.

Comment: The bag is an "overnight bag" or sometimes "grab bag". The little bag is just a "toiletries bag".

Comment: [Don't forget to bring your towel](https://www.google.com/search?q=don%27t+forget+to+bring+your+towel)

Comment: ... So pack accordingly.

Comment: We are going to a trip tomorrow and staying the night in a hotel. _Don't forget anything_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a way, it’s a strange thing to remind someone of right after you’ve just told them that they were going to be away for the night.  Perhaps it makes sense in some other context, but this sequence seems a bit unlikely:

> We’re going on an overnight trip, so don’t forget to bring whatever you need for that night and the next day, since you won’t have the chance to go back home and get it again after we leave.

If you really wanted to, though, I’d probably say not to forget one’s *overnight bag*.  I’ve also heard it called an *away bag*.

I wouldn’t feel pressed to outline what all I thought they should put in their bag unless it were something one did not normally think to pack, like bug-spray or alternate cell phone or fireworks or rattlesnake antivenin, or even toilet paper if I knew there wouldn’t otherwise be any available where we were overnighting.

I would trust an adult to know what standard things they’d need without coaching.  If this were a child without a custodial parent, I would of course be more careful, since children may not be used to packing for themselves.

Given that, you could also say *Don’t forget your toothbrush* in an informal, somewhat light-hearted way, sort of as a metonym for the whole kit and kaboodle.  I have occasionally heard people say that with this meaning.

Speaking of kits, a  [*dopp kit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopp_kit) is a genericized trademark for that little bag where you stash a copy of whatever you normally need from the bathroom.  Like, well, a toothbrush.  It’s the normal word I’ve always heard and used for that zippered little vinyl or leather case, and I was unaware it had any sort of brand affinity.

I suppose you **could** say *toiletries* or *toiletry kit*, but that runs a bit too close to potty training: in American, one often avoids saying the word “toilet” in any context whatsoever. It’s also getting more detailed than seems necessary in an adult context.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How about *overnight stuff*?

Comment: Well, you could. *Overnight stuff* is rather informal and indiscrete — albeit not indiscreet as referring to toilets might be. :)  I’d normally say *overnight bag* in most contexts.

Comment: I use *toiletries* all the time. *bathroomries* or *bathroomies* doesn't quite work. It's not unreasonable to [see this](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/airline-travel-regulations-toiletries-1591.html) in the news, either.

Comment: toiletries sounds about right to me

Comment: bizarre I've never heard of "dopp" kit.

Comment: I've never heard of a dopp kit as well, that name seems to refer to a particular commercial product and probably a term not used much anymore.  but overnight bag or travel bag would be what would come out of my mouth if I were discussing such things.

Comment: @stephenbayer Naw, it’s in [a lot of recent books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22dopp%20kit%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en). But I think it’s been xeroxed, kleenexed, and hoovered: I had no idea it referred to any particular brand. I thought it was just the normal name for that little kit/bag.

Comment: @JoeBlow I wouldn’t think to use it in capitals.  See the book references in the comment above.  Anyway, an overnight bag is not the same thing as a dopp kit.  A dopp kit contains your razor and toothbrush and such, whereas the overnight bag contains underwear and socks and a change of clothes — ***and*** the dopp kit, too.

Comment: I would say "overnight bag" too.  Never heard of a dopp kit, but from the link, it is NOT the same as overnight bag.  An overnight bag contains everything one needs for a night away, such as pajamas, toiletries, the next day's clothing, maybe even a book.  A toiletry bag refers to only personal hygiene items like a toothbrush and razors.  BTW I'm an American and nobody I know would avoid using the word "toilet".

Comment: It's wholly natural, normal, and commonplace to say "We'll be staying away tonight - take your overnight bag!" or "We'll be staying away tonight - take your stuff for staying away a night" or "We'll be staying away tonight, don't forget your overnight bag!"

Comment: The original (edit) question intended those sentences to be two lines. Use two spaces for breaks. This is the confusion between one user's monologue and a suggested dialog.

Answer (score 6):

I would say "Don't forget to bring your *essentials*."

According to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=hotel%20%22bring%20your%20essentials%22), the phrase "bring your essentials" is sometimes used when discussing packing for a trip.

Comment: First page of the search result does not show the actual number. So it is not "pretty" common but a nice word.

Comment: It's a nice alternate suggestion, but it highlights the fact that the **actual answer** to the question is simply **There is no single word for that.**  (Bearing in mind the wholly astounding staggering confusion here between toiletries bag, overnight bag, and [presumably what the OP meant] "the stuff you need for an overnight stay".)

Comment: I think the evidence from Google indicates that there is a single word for it.  After being given a context ("We are going on a trip tomorrow and staying the night in a hotel"), a person will know exactly what you mean when you say "Don't forget to bring your essentials."

Answer (score 0):

'kit'--(British) A collection of equipment or articles including clothes, usually for personal use when traveling. e.g. a travel kit; 'get your kit together, we're moving out'; 'Just one second while I get my kit'. 'I got kitted-out.' (issued personal stuff).'Helen Mirren is famous for taking her kit off.' I'm American but I use this word also.

Answer (score 0):

Just to say "remember your stuff", no matter how fancy a word you find for "stuff", seems only to serve as a warning that you'll be all "I told you so" if they miss anything.

I think you'd do better to spell out what they can expect to find at their accommodations--which, if you're in the position of reminding them about, I'm assuming you have some responsibility for, or at least familiarity with. And "remind" them specifically only of things which they might not realize they even need.

So, "This place provides towels and soap and shampoo." Or, "This place requires you to bring a sleep sack and your own pillow, and recommends we don't go barefoot or leave anything on the floor overnight."

Answer (score -1):

Since this is a single-word-request,  I'm going to officially give the new cultural norm answer which somebody has to give in cases where the answer is "There is no single word for that."

So, the answer to your question is:

**There is no single word for that.**

You'd have to say "your overnight stuff" or "your overnight things."

If your question is about the **luggage item** usually involved - that could be duffel, overnight bag, grab bag, small bag, overnight case, etc.

If your question is about the **small case thing that holds your toothbrush and other toiletries** that is called a toiletries bag, or see tchrist's answer.  (To be clear your toiletries bag is a little bag that sits in your overnight bag.)

It's a good question and it's interesting there is no single-word (or even phrase) for literally the **stuff** in question.

Comment: In this case, there _is_ a single word for that: _viaticum_ 
n, pl -ca  or -cums

3. money or necessities for any journey.

[Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary] (But I've fortunately managed to find a dictionary that says this usage is obsolete.)

Comment: To be fair the OP does say in the question title "word/phrase" and he has the "phrase-requests" tag. But I like the terms; *overnight bag/case*, and especially *grab bag*.

Comment: Hi Mari!  This whole QA is quite confusing!  It is quite astounding that it seems so difficult to differentiate between (A) a toiletries bag (it's a small bag the size of your hand which holds toiletries), (B) an overnight bag (it's a small piece of luggage, which holds a few tshirts, underwear, a toiletries bag, a laptop and an ipad), and (C) the **stuff** you need to take for an overnight, that is to say the **stuff** you put in an overnight bag.  It's all quite amazing. It's very disappointing that the OP won't explain which of these three is meant.

Comment: Hey Edwin, OP is asking for the viaticum for an overnight

Comment: You missed my point. I'll explain it again. The OP asks for a single word or *phrase* for "stuff" you bring with you overnight. I upvoted your post because it included the term, grab bag, which I think is pretty spot on. But the overall message is bordering on rudeness. The OP has explained sufficiently well what he was looking for, in your post you could have offered him many alternatives, and explained why,  without the need to preach. That's my honest opinion.

Comment: Let me edit this post, pleeaze. I can "fix" it! :)

Comment: Hi Mari!  Of course it's your right to edit any post!  You will not be able to **fix** it, as, it is **currently absolutely correct**.  This is the correct and final answer here.  Note that it already has a couple down votes, which on this site is total confirmation it is the only clear-thinking post.

Answer (score -1):

The word(s) you're looking for are "toiletries," or "sundries."